# Same ID Different Value become one row

Tags: mysql, sql

i need query for some value with same ID in many rows to become one row

this is myssql

```
select id,
case when a.id = b.id then b.name  else null end as ModelName
from Unit a
inner join Product b
on a.id = b.id 
where a.id = 36239

36239    PAN FEEDER 1000MM X 1500MM 
36239   NS 400 GYRATORY CONE CRUSHER    
36239   NH 400 TERTIARY CONE CRUSHER    
36239   SCALPING SCREEN 6'X12'X2 DECK   
36239    PRODUCT VIBRATING SCREEN 8'X20'X3 DECK 
36239   ADPLUS PAN FEEDER 900 X 1500    
36239   GRIZZLY FEEDER DHS 6
```

my expected result is

```
36239 PAN FEEDER 1000MM X 1500MM NS 400 GYRATORY CONE CRUSHER NH 400 TERTIARY CONE CRUSHER
```

Comment: That case expression makes no sense at all. The first condition will always be true.

Comment: Poor sample data. You should have a few different id values to make the problem clearer.

Answer (score 0):

use `group_concat()`

```
select a.id ,group_concat(b.name SEPARATOR ' ')
from Unit a
inner join Product b
on a.id = b.id  
where a.id = 36239
group by a.id
```

Comment: Put GROUP BY after WHERE.

Comment: And qualify the select list's id column.

Comment: Specify the separator for `group_concat()`: default is the comma, OP seems to want a space